# bottom left corner shading effect in css or css3

Tags: css

[image: Graphic Design Image]

I need help to create the styling shown in the image above which is a graphic design of what I am needing to do. The bottom left hand corner shading for the panels shown in the image above is my real sticking point.
I have tried all sorts of generators but I just can't get close enough with radial gradients.

As you can see I have a number of panels (actually 5 in total) lined up next to each other, each panel is a different width potentially and will resize with borwser view port sizing so providing a background image is not really an option.

I have a repeating transparent background image that creates the texture effect that works fine so I am not concerned about the texture effect but I am totally unable to create the bottom left corner darker shading effect and I need to get as close as absolutely possible using css. I have been tearing my hair out over this for days.

The main green colour hex code is #3F4B0B

My css currently looks like this

```
@mixin forest-green-texture{
    @include background-image(url("texture.png"), linear_gradient($dark-green, $light-green));
}
.footer-box{
    @include banner-color;
    @include forest-green-texture();
    width:18%;
    float:left;
}
```

The linear gradient just doesn't cut it! It was my last attempt and totally wrong

I am using SASS if that makes a difference

I got pretty close using this tool http://ie.microsoft.com/TESTDRIVE/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html

which gave me

```
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */  background-image:
-ms-radial-gradient(right top, circle farthest-side, #3F4B0B 0%, #3F4B0B 70%, #3F4B0B 90%, #000000 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(right top, circle farthest-side, #3F4B0B 0%, #3F4B0B 70%, #3F4B0B 90%,
#000000 100%);

/* Opera */  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(right top, circle farthest-side, #3F4B0B 0%, #3F4B0B 70%, #3F4B0B 90%, #000000 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */  background-image:
-webkit-gradient(radial, right top, 0, right top, 970, color-stop(0, #3F4B0B), color-stop(0.7, #3F4B0B), color-stop(0.9, #3F4B0B), color-stop(1, #000000));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */  background-image:
-webkit-radial-gradient(right top, circle farthest-side, #3F4B0B 0%, #3F4B0B 70%, #3F4B0B 90%, #000000 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at right top, #3F4B0B 0%, #3F4B0B 70%, #3F4B0B 90%, #000000 100%);
```

I know the colours are slightly wrong, I'm not bothered about that I can adjust them but the above wasn't really much better than a linear gradient.

**UPDATE**
This is a screen shot of what I have managed to achieve so far

[image: Site Screen Shor]

As you can see, the shading just isn't right.
The css I have for this is

```
background-image: url("texture.png"), linear-gradient(to right top, black 0%, rgb(70, 84, 12) 50%, rgb(82, 97, 14) 100%);
```

All help greatly appreciated

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you want the gradient to look like the example picture? Or is the picture an illustration of what you have now but you want to improve on it?

Comment: @MrLister I need the gradient to look like the example picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting the textured image on the background of the container div of the columns then for each column use that line shadow image with transparent background as the background property for each colum.

```
<style>

  .container {
    background: url(textureImg.png) repeat;
  }

  div[class^="col"] {
    background: url(lineShadowImg.png) no-repeat;
  }

</style>

<div class='container'>

  <div class='colOne'>
    //your content
  </div>

  <div class='colTwo'>
    //your content
  </div>

  <div class='colThree'>
    //your content
  </div>

</div>
```

If you need to tweak the positioning of the line just use background-position. This will allow your columns to be as wide as they need to be without having to change your image for each.